# Where is this php directive being overriden

Tags: apache-httpd, php

The error message `AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 17826104 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown` is normally fixed by changing the pair of related settings for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in php.ini.

The issue I have is that the it appears to ignore the setting set in php.ini.

The settings are configured as follow in php.ini:

```bash
root@server8:/etc/php$ grep -e post_max -e upload_max /etc/php/8.2/fpm/php.ini
post_max_size = 16M
upload_max_filesize = 16M
```

Using `phpinfo()` I can see the values for `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` as as 8M and 2M respectively.  I am trying to find out where these settings are being overriden.

Using `phpinfo()` I looked at the value for `Additional .ini files parsed` and `Scan this dir for additional .ini files` to see if any files there set these directives.  They do not.

```bash
root@server8:/# directive_list=$(echo /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/15-xml.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-curl.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-dom.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-exif.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-ffi.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-gd.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-iconv.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-memcache.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-phar.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-posix.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-redis.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-sockets.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-xsl.ini, /etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-zip.ini | tr -d ',')
root@server8:/# echo $directive_list | xargs grep max_
/etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/20-memcache.ini:; memcache.max_failover_attempts="20"
root@server8:/#
```

I checked whether any of the Apache config files are overriding the settings, they do not:

```bash
root@server8:/etc/php$ find /etc/apache2 -name "*conf" | xargs grep max_
root@server8:/etc/php$ find /etc/apache2 -name "*conf" | xargs grep filesize
root@server8:/etc/php$ find /etc/apache2 -name "*conf" | xargs grep post_
root@server8:/etc/php$
```

I checked whether there are any settings in .htaccess that may override these settings:

```bash
root@server8:/$ find $vhostdir/../ -name .htaccess 
root@server8:/$
```

(I also checked further up the path)

Out of desperation I also checked the php.ini files for all other versions of PHP installed to see if any of them were used, despite what was reported by `phpinfo()`

```bash
root@server8:/etc/php$ find . -type f |xargs grep upload_max
./8.2/apache2/php.ini:upload_max_filesize = 16M
./8.2/fpm/php.ini:upload_max_filesize = 16M
./8.2/cli/php.ini:upload_max_filesize = 16M
./7.4/apache2/php.ini:upload_max_filesize = 16M
./7.4/fpm/php.ini:upload_max_filesize = 16M
./7.4/cli/php.ini:upload_max_filesize = 16M
./8.1/apache2/php.ini:upload_max_filesize = 16M
./8.1/fpm/php.ini:upload_max_filesize = 16M
./8.1/cli/php.ini:upload_max_filesize = 16M
root@server8:/etc/php$ find . -type f |xargs grep post_max
./8.2/apache2/php.ini:post_max_size = 16M
./8.2/fpm/php.ini:post_max_size = 16M
./8.2/cli/php.ini:post_max_size = 16M
./7.4/apache2/php.ini:post_max_size = 16M
./7.4/fpm/php.ini:post_max_size = 16M
./7.4/cli/php.ini:post_max_size = 16M
./8.1/apache2/php.ini:post_max_size = 16M
./8.1/fpm/php.ini:post_max_size = 16M
./8.1/cli/php.ini:post_max_size = 16M
root@server8:/etc/php$
```

So where else may these be derived from?  Is the php.ini file mentioned by `phpinfo()` actually being used?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the php.ini file mentioned by phpinfo() actually being used?

Yes - and that's a good place to start (rather than looking where you think the php.ini file might be).

They [can be overridden](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) in the webserver config, and (at least in the case of Apache) in .htaccess files as well as additional .ini files. And bear in mind that webserver overrides mapped to speific paths, .htaccess and PHP_INI_PERDIR overrides will only aply to specific directory trees (i.e. make sure you're checking phpinfo() in the same dir where the script reporting the error resides). Creating a test script with `print ini_get("upload_max_filesize") . " / " ini_get("post_max_size");` might be helpful.

You might also want to scan your code for `init_set`.

Comment: I will have a look through the site code for any init_set statements.  But to confirm I did put the php_info() call in a file in the site directory.

Comment: Doing `find . -type f |xargs grep -c init_set` in the site directory, all files are listed with 0 hits per file.

Comment: A coleague found the solution.  This specific server has php-fpm installed.  This service needed to be restarted for it to learn the new settings.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer by @symcbean is valuable in terms of confirming the process and questions I had about this, the answer was that I needed to restart php-fpm.

```bash
systemct restart php8.2-fpm
```

The issue was that php-fpm had loaded a configuration and this is what was used, and changes to the respective php ini files were not being picked up because the running service had a resident configuration.

Once the service was restarted, everything worked as expected.

It is worth noting that one needs to restart apache2 also for changes to php.ini files to take effect.